# Having Issues Uploading WAR File to WebSphere 6.1

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, jersey, war

I'm trying to deploy a web service onto WebSphere using a WAR file, which I have been told directly is completely possible and has been done many times before.  WebSphere allows me to upload the file, specify the context root, and even start the application.  However, when I try to access it by specifying my underlying URIs, WebSphere 404s on me.  The relatively useless error message displayed is:

`Error 404: SRVE0202E: Servlet [Jersey REST Service]: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer was found, but is corrupt: SRVE0227I: 1. Check that the class resides in the proper package directory. SRVE0228I: 2. Check that the classname has been defined in the server using the proper case and fully qualified package. SRVE0229I: 3. Check that the class was transferred to the filesystem using a binary transfer mode. SRVE0230I: 4. Check that the class was compiled using the proper case (as defined in the class definition). SRVE0231E: 5. Check that the class file was not renamed after it was compiled.`

I have checked my naming conventions, modified my web.xml according to [this](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/07/cant-deploy-war-on-websphere-6.html) blog post, attempted [packaging it into an ear file](http://www.websphere-world.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=401) (which threw out its own errors when I tried to upload it), and am trying to figure out what configurations I might have wrong.  Any ideas of what I could change to make this work?

**Edit**

Here is the relevant part of my web.xml file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"

id="WebAppId"

xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"

xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>MYPROJECT'SDISPLAYNAME</display-name>

    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>

            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>

            <param-value>MYPROJECTNAME</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>`

**Another Edit**

I'm using the newest release of Jersey- is that part of the problem?

**Yet Another Edit**

I'm pretty sure that's the entire problem. WebSphere 6.1 runs jdk1.5, and Jersey stopped supporting that after Jersey 1.2...

Comment: can you share structure and config files of war file.

Comment: @Kamahire I've exported it from Eclipse, so I'm not sure of everything that's getting included, but my classes call different methods based upon the URI entered (i.e. root/foo/bar would call MethodA, root/foo/bar/party would call MethodB). I'll add the relevant snippet of my web.xml file that's getting included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect your problem is lack for WebSphere support for Jersey (or rather JAX-RS).

I don't see JAX-RS in the list of supported APIs by WAS.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.ic.WS.doc/info_sching.html

WAS 6.1 runs on J2SE 1.5 (as seen in the URL above)

**Specification or API                       Version 6.1**

Java 2 Standard Edition (J2SE) specification J2SE 5

These probably are the reasons behind the errors that you get to see in your WAS 6.1

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Yeah, this is it. I downgraded to Jersey 1.2 (which also runs J2SE 1.5) and got it to upload, now I'm just getting other errors that I need to hammer out.

Comment: ...And those other errors were a result of more drivers that were incompatible with J2SE 1.5 that I needed to downgrade as well.